# Two domains pointed to the same server

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have one domain that points to **UVPS** server **Ubuntu 20.04**. We have a **Puma webserver** running on this server.

Once we decided to buy another domain and point it to the same website. So user can easily type either domain1.de or domain2.de and open the same website.

SO the problem is that I need somehow configurate the new domain on the Ubuntu server (not a webserver).

I added **CNAME** record for hosting's DNS.

I changed **/etc/hosts** and added the second record. Currently **hosts** looks like that:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server.domain1.de server
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx server.domain2.de server
```

Currently **dnsdomainname** returns only one domain

```
root@server: dnsdomainname
domain1.de
```

And list of **fdqn** records contain only one domain also.

```
root@server: hostname -A
localhost server.domain1.de
```

I have a guess that we need to add a new **FQDN**, correct me if I'm wrong, so that server could return both domains but don't have an idea how. Or probably I'm totally wrong and there is another way to achieve that. The support of our hosting told that we need set a new domain up on the server, but I don't know how.

I would be really appreciate if you give me some hints.

Comment: How is the server set up currently?  Does it have a web server installed to serve data?  If so you have to configure that web server to be domain aware and serve different data for a different domain.

Comment: Please try to decribe **as exactly as possible**: 1) what happens currently when you connect to the server; 2) what do you want to happen. Your current description is very vague and it is hard to understand anything out of it.

Comment: @ThomasWard Yes, currently server has a web server and website is working fine. Server is Puma with RubyOnRails. I can configure the server but the problem is that my domain is not visible by DNS.

Comment: @raj, Thank you in advance =)
1) Currently the Puma web-server working on that server. So if I type the domain1.de in the browser then website is opened. 
2) We bought a new one domain and want that domain to point to the same server. For example if user type in the browser **domain1.de** or **domain2.de** then the same website is opened. SO I assume that it is something to do with DNS, because currently no DNS sees this domain. Once DNS will be set up I would configure webserver.

Comment: @raj I want both domains to work, currently only one domain is visible to DNS, I need to make visible the second domain and work as first one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because setting up DNS for a domain is not an Ubuntu problem.

Comment: @OrganicMarble it's not exactly setting up DNS, it's general question and setting up FQDN on Ubuntu it is directly tied to Ubuntu

Comment: Have you pointed dns from domain2 to the new server? That should basically do it.

Comment: Have you already registered domain2.de ? Once you register it, you should assign the same IP address to domain2.de as to domain1.de. Basically that should be enough, you don't need to configure anything on the server itself.